# Idle time-out for a background thread on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

IIS Version :7.5,
Idle time-out for the ApplicationPool: 20 minutes.

step:
1. User visits a page.
2. when the server receives the request, a new thread is created by the code to process an complex operation. And at the same time, the response is sent to the user saying that the request is processed in the background.

After 20 minute(no visit to the site), the worker process is shut down. The complex operation has not been finished.

How to make the iis know that the worker process is not idle if a thead is running?

Comment: Remove the shut down if idle from the pool, or make a service run your operation, or make a console application to run your operations, and run it from command line, from asp.net.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know work around about this issue. But I also want to know why this issue happens? How to define the idle phase of the worker porcess?

Comment: I believe that is impossible to know that the background threads are working and the pool is just checking for new connections and request from the web.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem at this tame, currently found the best solution just create new request from IIS worker thread to IIS itself to avoid background thread shutdown.